# How to integrate paypal in laravel

Tags: laravel, paypal

when PayPal form request in controller error occurs this

```
Object of class Illuminate\Routing\Redirector could not be converted to string
```

Error in Controller I think this function create error setExpressCheckout()

```php
$provider = new ExpressCheckout;
    
$response = $provider->setExpressCheckout($data);
    
$response = $provider->setExpressCheckout($data, true);
    
return redirect($response['paypal_link']);
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You may redirect to a domain outside of your application by calling the `away` method:

```php
return redirect()->away($response['paypal_link']);
```

See [Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/master/responses#redirecting-external-domains) for more info.